# Edit Custom Footer with Astra Theme and Beaver Builder

Tags: themes, datastax-astra

I am trying to access a custom footer that has been created with Astra Theme and Beaver Builder.  In Astra Custom Layouts there appears to be a published Footer but when I try to access it (it says it was built with Beaver Builder) all I see is a blank space below a Header built with Beaver Builder.

The child theme used has a Footer.php with the following code:

````
```<?php
````

````
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
 }

 ?>
         <?php astra_content_bottom(); ?>

         </div> <!-- ast-container -->

     </div><!-- #content -->

     <?php astra_content_after(); ?>

     <?php astra_footer_before(); ?>

     <?php astra_footer(); ?>

     <?php astra_footer_after(); ?>

 </div><!-- #page -->

 <?php astra_body_bottom(); ?>

 <?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
     var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

     $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
     //$(this).parents('#tabs').next('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
     $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

     $(this).addClass('current');
     $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 });
 
 $('.hmbutton4 a').click(function(){
     $("li#menu-item-2396 .sub-menu ").addClass('open');
 });
});
 
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
 
//  $('.yellow-btn a').click(function(){
//      $( "li#armoury" ).trigger( "click" );
//  });

 //if(window.location.href === "https://brand-rightdev.com/springfield/availability/#armoury"){
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("/availability/#armoury") != -1) {
     $( "li#armourygardens" ).trigger( "click" );
 }
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("/availability/#belmont") != -1) {
     $( "li#belmontgardens" ).trigger( "click" );
 }
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("/availability/#northern") != -1) {
     $( "li#northerngardens" ).trigger( "click" );
 }

});
 
</script>```


When I look at inspector at the visible Footer on the website I see this:

     ```
 <div class="fl-row-content-wrap">
                             <div class="fl-row-content fl-row-fixed-width fl-node-content">```

 ```<div class="fl-col-group fl-node-5e9c925e7d898" data-node="5e9c925e7d898">
         <div class="fl-col fl-node-5e9c925e7d9c2 fl-col-small" data-node="5e9c925e7d9c2">
 <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content"><div class="fl-module fl-module-photo fl-node-5e9c9266b2b30" data-node="5e9c9266b2b30">
 <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
     <div class="fl-photo fl-photo-align-left" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
 <div class="fl-photo-content fl-photo-img-png">
             <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" class="fl-photo-img wp-image-2311 size-full" src="https://springfieldgardensma.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Springfield-new-logo-1.png" alt="Springfield-new-logo (1)" itemprop="image" srcset="https://springfieldgardensma.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Springfield-new-logo-1.png 384w, https://springfieldgardensma.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Springfield-new-logo-1-300x220.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 384px) 100vw, 384px" title="Springfield-new-logo (1)" width="384" height="281">
                 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>```

 ```<div class="fl-col fl-node-5faadd4b2c0c7 fl-col-small" data-node="5faadd4b2c0c7">
 <div class="fl-col-content fl-node-content"><div class="fl-module fl-module-heading fl-node-5faadab0f35af" data-node="5faadab0f35af">
 <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
     <h5 class="fl-heading">
     <span class="fl-heading-text">LEASING OFFICE</span>```
     

as part of the footer code which shows an image on the left then a second column with some text etc.

Can anyone advise how I can open this footer as I want to make some edits to the text area and at the moment I cannot find anyway to do so.

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok No need to respond to this as it seems an out-of-date theme was the cause.  Sometimes the easiest answers are the best option!

Comment: You can close and update the question instead of put an answer like this

Comment: If I could find how to close the question I would. Please point me in the right direction or if you can close it please do so